# How to add record in pandas dataframe dynamically in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

df:

```
   Month    Product  Start_Date End_Date   Updated_on 
0 January   Beverage 01/01/2020 01/31/2020 02/06/2020 
1 February  Beverage 02/01/2020 02/29/2020 03/06/2020 
2 March     Beverage 03/01/2020 03/31/2020 04/06/2020 
3 April     Beverage 04/01/2020 04/30/2020 05/06/2020 
4 May       Beverage 05/01/2020 05/31/2020 06/06/2020
```

how to add a row in python dataframe for next month dynamically. for example my df last row is:

```
4 May Beverage 05/01/2020 05/31/2020 06/06/2020
```

so i need to add one more row for June ie,

```
5 June Beverage 06/01/2020 05/30/2020 06/07/2020
```

every time if you run a script one row should be added for next month and so on.

output:

```
   Month    Product  Start_Date End_Date   Updated_on 
0 January   Beverage 01/01/2020 01/31/2020 02/06/2020 
1 February  Beverage 02/01/2020 02/29/2020 03/06/2020 
2 March     Beverage 03/01/2020 03/31/2020 04/06/2020 
3 April     Beverage 04/01/2020 04/30/2020 05/06/2020 
4 May       Beverage 05/01/2020 05/31/2020 06/06/2020
5 June      Beverage 06/01/2020 05/30/2020 06/07/2020
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using dictionary

You can create a dictionary containing data to be added to the dataframe :

```py
new_row = {
    'Month': 'June',
    'Product': 'Beverage',
    'Start_Date': '06/01/2020',
    'End_Date': '05/30/2020',
    'Updated_on': '06/07/2020'
}
```

Then by using `df.append` you can add it to the dataframe:

```py
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

The result will be the following:

```py
    Month     Product   Start_Date  End_Date    Updated_on
0   January   Beverage  01/01/2020  01/31/2020  02/06/2020
1   February  Beverage  02/01/2020  02/29/2020  03/06/2020
2   March     Beverage  03/01/2020  03/31/2020  04/06/2020
3   April     Beverage  04/01/2020  04/30/2020  05/06/2020
4   May       Beverage  05/01/2020  05/31/2020  06/06/2020
5   June      Beverage  06/01/2020  05/30/2020  06/07/2020
```

### Using list

You can also append rows by passing a list:

```py
new_row = ['June', 'Beverage', '06/01/2020', '05/30/2020', '06/07/2020']
```

Then, you can use `.loc` to create a new row based on the index provided. For instance, if your index is basically the length of your dataframe, you can add a new row using:

```py
df.loc[len(df)] = new_row
```

With this second option, you can manually specify the index of your new row. In your example, the index is `5`. Therefore you can add a new row at the index 5 using `df.loc[5] = new_row`.

### Automatic filling of new row

First step is to convert your `Start_Date` and `End_Date` to datetime:

```py
df['Start_Date'] = df.Start_Date.apply(pd.Timestamp)
df['End_Date'] = df.End_Date.apply(pd.Timestamp)
df['Updated_on'] = df.Updated_on.apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Then I can automatically fill information of the new row, based on the information in the last row of your dataframe. I assumed the `Updated_on` column to be filled using current time.

```
last_row = df.iloc[-1]

new_row = {
    'Month': (last_row.Start_Date + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).month_name(),
    'Product': last_row.Product,
    'Start_Date': last_row.Start_Date + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1),
    'End_Date':  last_row.End_Date + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1), 
    'Updated_on': pd.Timestamp.now()
}

df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: But this has to be dynamic, creating a list or dictionary everytime would not make it dynamic. It should check last row and create a record as per last row for next month.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic ? What are your new data supposed to be constructed ? For the month, start_date and end_date I see, but for the updated_on I would need more details :)

Comment: I edited my answer. The last part of it explains how to add a new row based on information contained in the last one in the dataframe. Please let me know if there is any change to be made!

Comment: if I need to run this script automatically in every month at particular date, how can we do that?

Comment: Then it becomes a task scheduling problem, maybe you can find some valuable information here: https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-your-python-scripts-with-task-scheduler-661d0a40b279

Comment: This answer is deprecated and needs an update as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956237/191246